# Button.wait_variable usage in Python/Tkinter

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, wait

There have already been several topics on Python/Tkinter, but I did not find an answer in them for the issue described below.
The two Python scripts below are reduced to the bare essentials to keep it simple. The first one is a simple Tkinter window with a button, and the script needs to wait till the button is clicked:

```
from tkinter import *
windowItem1 = Tk()
windowItem1.title("Item1")
WaitState = IntVar()
def submit():
      WaitState.set(1)
      print("submitted")
button = Button(windowItem1, text="Submit", command=submit)
button.grid(column=0, row=1)
      
print("waiting...")
button.wait_variable(WaitState)
print("done waiting.")  
windowItem1.mainloop()
```

This works fine, and we see the printout “done waiting” when the button is clicked.

The second script adds one level: we first have a menu window, and when clicking the select button of the first presented item, we have a new window opening with the same as above. However, when clicking the submit button, I don’t get the “Done waiting”. I’m stuck on the `wait_variable`.

```
from tkinter import *
windowMenu = Tk()
windowMenu.title("Menu")
def SelectItem1():
      windowItem1 = Tk()
      windowItem1.title("Item1")
      WaitState = IntVar()    
      
      def submit():
            WaitState.set(1)
            print("submitted")
      button = Button(windowItem1, text="Submit", command=submit)
      button.grid(column=0, row=1)
      
      print("waiting...")
      button.wait_variable(WaitState)
      print("done waiting")   
      
lblItem1 = Label(windowMenu, text="Item 1 : ")
lblItem1.grid(column=0, row=0)
btnItem1 = Button(windowMenu, text="Select", command=SelectItem1)
btnItem1.grid(column=1, row=0)
windowMenu.mainloop()
```

Can you explain it?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `SelectItem1` function, you do `windowItem1 = Tk()`. You shouldn't use `Tk()` to initialize multiple windows in your application, the way to think about `Tk()` is that it creates a specialized `tkinter.Toplevel` window that is considered to be the main window of your entire application. Creating multiple windows using `Tk()` means multiple main windows, and each one would need its own `mainloop()` invokation, which is... yikes.

Try this instead:

`windowItem1 = Toplevel()`

Comment: Hi Paul, I've spent hours investigating the code and google but I didn't find any clear explanation. Do not see clearly the link between your answer and my question, but it works ! (and I'll look for some more explanation on Toplevel later on) Problem solved. Thank you very much !!